# Create JSON from specific lines of data

Tags: python, json

I have this test data that I am trying to use to create a JSON for just select items. I have the items listed and would just like to output a JSON list with select item.

What I have:

```py
import json

  
# Data to be written

dictionary ={

  "id": "04",

  "name": "sunil",

  "department": "HR"
}

  
# Serializing json 

x= json.dumps(dictionary,indent=0)

# JSON String

y = json.loads(x)
```

```
# Goal is to print:

{

  "id": "04",

  "name": "sunil"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to save the department key you can use this:

```
del y['department']
```

Then your y variable will print what you wanted:

```
{"id": "04", "name": "sunil"}
```

[Other ways to solve the same issue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary/)

Comment: Is there a way I can delete all combinations except ID and name? My real dictionary has 97 items of which I need 15

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in list(y.keys()):
#add all potential keys you want to remain in the final dictionary
if key == "id" or key == "name":
   continue
else:
   del y[key]
```

However, iterating over a dictionary is pretty slow. You could assign values to temporary variables and then remake the dictionary like this:

```
temp_id = y['id']
temp_name = y['name']
y.clear()
y['id'] = temp_id
y['name'] = temp_name
```

This should be faster that iterating over a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get it to work and used it in my live data to extract and then post the call I wanted back to the API. I used a keep list and a filter I need to understand a little better. I learned a lot on dictionary and that was the best part!

Comment: Amazing to hear, glad I could help!